# Access guildMember via event handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to ask how to access a guildMember via an event handler.

Here is how I'm supposed to write it (and so many others have done this too)...

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {
    let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Member');

    guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('TheChannelID').send(`Welcome, <@${guildMember.user.id}>, to our server! ... Check out the rules-cmd channel!`);
});
```

...but I have an event handler, shown below...

```
//My event handler
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) =>{
    const load_dir = (dirs) =>{
        const event_files = fs.readdirSync(`./events/${dirs}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
        
        for (const file of event_files) {
            const event = require(`../events/${dirs}/${file}`);
            const event_name = file.split('.')[0];
            client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, Discord, client));
        }
    }

    ['client', 'guild'].forEach(e => load_dir(e));
}
```

and here is my ATTEMPT at trying to recreate this in a separate guildMemberAdd.js file, but nothing seems to be working...

```
module.exports = (Discord, client, message) =>{
    const guildMember = Discord.GuildMember;
    let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Member');

    guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('TheChannelID').send(`Welcome, <@${guildMember.user.id}>, to our server! ... Check out the rules-cmd channel!`);
}
```

I have scrunched up my head for hours pondering the problem, can anybody help please?

Oh, and I got most of my code from CodeLyon. He taught it to us this way...

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {
    let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Member');

    guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('TheChannelID').send(`Welcome, <@${guildMember.user.id}>, to our server! ... Check out the rules-cmd channel!`);
});
```

...but he didn't tell us how to do it when he made his event handler. I fixed the member counter problem that people were asking in the comments, but I can't seem to fix this problem.

Here's CodeLyon's tutorials...
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbbLC0BLaGjpyzN1rg-gK4dUqbn8eJQq4

**PLEASE it will be of great appreciation if someone could help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is almost working, your setup has it so that the arguments are in this order: `(Discord, client, [parameters of the event here])`

This means that you need to change your

```
module.exports = (Discord, client, message) =>{
```

to

```
module.exports = (Discord, client, guildMember) =>{
```

as your "message" for guildMemberAdd event currently is the guildmember object, so to avoid confusion, changing it will make it work.